# How to read HID devices (/dev/hidrawX) with Qt on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, hid

I'm working on a 'RepRap calibration tool' which would use a mouse attached to the printing platform to measure the movement of the platform.

Right now I'm stuck trying to read raw mouse data from `/dev/hidrawX`, but I'm unable to read any data.

So far I've tried:

#### First attempt:

```
QFile f("/dev/hidraw0");
f.readAll();
```

Reads nothing.

#### Second attempt:

```
m_file = new QFile("/dev/hidraw0");
m_sn= new QSocketNotifier(m_file->handle(), QSocketNotifier::Read);
m_sn->setEnabled(true);
connect(m_sn, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
```

then on the readyRead SLOT:

```
qDebug()<<"Ready Read!!"<<m_file.bytesAvailable();
QTextStream d(&m_file);
qDebug()<< d.read(64);
```

This code fires the readyRead slot once but it gets stuck on the read(64) call, if I comment the read(64) the slot will be fired each time the mouse its moved.
`m_file.bytesAvailable()` always reports 0.

Which is the right way to read these devices with Qt?

## Solution:

I reworked the code like:

```
bool rcMouseHandler::openHidraw(QString device)
{
    int fd =open(device.toLocal8Bit(),O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fd <=0)
    {
        qDebug()<<"[WARN]rcMouseHandler::open-> Cant open!";
        return false;
    }
    m_sn= new QSocketNotifier(fd, QSocketNotifier::Read);
    m_sn->setEnabled(true);
    connect(m_sn, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
    return true;
}

void rcMouseHandler::readyRead()
{
    qDebug()<<"Ready Read!!";
    char buffer[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    read(m_sn->socket(),&buffer,4);
    qDebug()<<(quint8)buffer[0]<<(quint8)buffer[1]<<(quint8)buffer[2]<<(quint8)buffer[3];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way I suppose here to not use Qt. Why you need portable wrapper above POSIX open and read, when this part of your code is not portable (part that work with /dev/*). Open device with "open" "man 2 open" in O_NONBLOCK and call "read" (man 2 read) to get data from it. And you can still use QSocketNotifier with handle that return "open".

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem :)
Effectively I don't need portable solution for reading the mouse, I'll be using linux only. Just thought that QT should have something for managing this situation.

Comment: I faced the same problem when I want to work with device via RS232 long time ago. At now qt5 have qserial<bla-bla> class for it, at that time (several years back) there was 3rd party solution for it (they inherit QIODevice and do magic), I spend several hours debuging protocol + this third party library, at the end I just swithc to "open + read" and all become robust. Qt solve general problem, QFile is for regular files.